# Full path and wildcard with file extension in Windows commandline program

Tags: windows, batch-processing

What I would like to acheive is to have a certain command in right (context menu) in every Windows folder. I have the right registry key but when I put my command:

```
nconvert.exe -overwrite -ratio -resize 1400 0  %1\*.jpg
```

it does not work. How to fix this?

Comment: What happens instead?  Does it throw an error?  Or does nothing happen?

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around the parameter: `"%1\.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

All was needed is :

```
"%1\*.jpg"
```